# Audio Recording/Mixer Software

Tags: c++, audio, windows-xp

As a guitarist I have always wanted to develop my own recording, mixing software. I have some experience in Direct Sound, Windows Multimedia (waveOutOpen, etc). I realise that this will be a complex project, but is purely for my own use and learning, i.e. no deadlines! I intend to use C++ but as yet am unsure as the best SDK/API to use. I want the software to be extensible as I may wish to add effects in the future. A few prerequisites...

1. To run on Windows XP
2. Minimal latency
3. VU meter (on all tracks)
   This caused me to shy away from Direct Sound as there doesn't appear to be a way to read audio data from the primary buffer.
4. Overdubbing (i.e. record a new track whilst playing existing tracks).
5. Include a metronome

My initial thoughts are to use WMM and use the waveOutWrite function to play audio data. I guess this is essentially an audio streaming player. To try and keep things simpler, I will hard-code the sample rate to 16-bit, 44.1kHZ (the best sampling rate my sound card supports). What I need are some ideas, guidance on an overall architecture.

For example, assume my tempo is 60 BPM and time signature is 4/4. I want the metronome to play a click at the start of every bar/measure. Now assume that I have recorded a rhythm track. Upon playback I need to orchestrate (pun intended) what data is sent to the primary sound buffer. I may also, at some point, want to add instruments, drums (mainly). Again, I need to know how to send the correct audio data, at the correct time to the primary audio buffer. I appreciate timing is key here. What I am unsure of is how to grab correct data from individual tracks to send to the primary sound buffer.

My initial thoughts are to have a timing thread which periodically asks each track, "I need data to cover N milliseconds of play". Where N depends upon the primary buffer size.

I appreciate that this is a complex question, I just need some guidance as to how I might approach some of the above problems.

An additional question is WMM or DirectSound better suited for my needs. Maybe even ASIO? However, the main question is how, using a streaming mechanism, do I gather the correct track data (from multiple tracks) to send to a primary buffer, and keep minimal latency?

Any help is appreciated,

Many thanks

Karl

Thanks for the responses. However, my main question is how to time all of this, to ensure that each track writes appropriate data to the primary buffer, at the correct time. I am of course open to (free) libraries that will help me achieve my main goals.

Comment: A note on API choice: Starting Vista, a new API (WASAPI) specifically targets low latency audio via its [exclusive-mode streams](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd370844%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). This is the best easy way to deal with low latency audio in Windows. In XP for similar low latency I suppose you will have to use ASIO.

Comment: Thanks Roman, yes, I have considered ASIO as this is purely an XP project.

Comment: Of course, you should consider PortAudio as well, which lets you access ASIO and other APIs.

Comment: Your "main question" isn't really a specific question. Have you tried writing any code yet? What hasn't worked? WHy are you unable to schedule the buffers from multiple tracks to arrive at the same time?

Comment: I wasn't sure how to write correct track data to the primary buffer. For example, depending upon the tempo and primary buffer size, metronome data might have to be written several times. For a previously recorded track I would send a chunk equal to the primary buffer size until all track data has been sent. Based upon Joe's answer, I think I need to calculate the time frame from the primary buffer size. I can then calculate the number of beats that fit within the time frame. I can then determine the number of samples (metronome, drum, etc) to write to the primary buffer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you intend to support XP (which I would *not* recommend, as even the extended support will end next year) you really have no choice but to use ASIO. The appropriate SDK can be downloaded from [Steinberg](http://www.steinberg.net/en/company/developer.html). In Windows Vista and above [WASAPI Exclusive Mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd370844%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) might be a better option due to wider availability, however the documentation is severely lacking IMO. In any case, you should have a look at [PortAudio](http://www.portaudio.com/) which helps wrap these APIs (and unlike [Juce](http://www.juce.com/) is free.

Neither WMM nor DirectSound nor XAudio 2 will be able to achieve sufficiently low latencies for realtime monitoring. Low-latency APIs usually periodically call a callback for each block of data.

As every callback processes a given number of samples, you can calculate the time from the sample rate and a sample counter (simply accumulate across callback calls). Tip: do not accumulate with floating point. That way lies madness. Use a 64 bit sample counter, as the smallest increment is always `1./sampleRate`.

Effectively your callback function would (for each track) call a `getSamples(size_t n, float* out)` (or similar) method and sum up the results (i.e. mix them). Each individual track could would then have an integrated sample time to compute what is currently required. For periodic things (infinite waves, loops, metronomes) you can easily calculate the number of samples per period and have a modulo counter. That would lead to rounded periods, but as mentioned before, floating point accumulators are a no-no, they can work ok for periodic signals though.

In the case of the metronome example you might have a waveform "click.wav" with `n` samples and a period of `m` samples. Your counter periodically goes from `0` to `m-1` and as long as the counter is less than `n` you play the corresponding sample of your waveform. For example a simple metronome that plays a click each beat could look something like this:

```
class Metronome
{
    std::vector<float> waveform;
    size_t counter, period;

public:
    Metronome(std::vector<float> const & waveform, float bpm, float sampleRate) : waveform(waveform), counter(0)
    {
        float secondsPerBeat = 60.f/bpm; // bpm/60 = bps
        float samplesPerBeat = sampleRate * secondsPerBeat;
        period = (size_t)round(samplesPerBeat);
    }

    void getSamples(size_t n, float* out)
    {
        while(n--)
        {
            *out++ = counter < waveform.size() ? waveform[counter] : 0.f;
            counter += 1;
            counter -= counter >= period ? period : 0;
        }
    }
};
```

Furthermore you could check the internet for VST/AU Plugin programming tutorials, as these have the same "problem" of determining time from the number of samples.

Comment: Thanks Joe, I wasn't suggesting a separate thread for each track, that would be madness :-)
I am currently stuck with XP as I use for work stuff as well.

Comment: Guess I misread that sentence. In any case you won't need your own "timing thread", due to the periodically called callback (which will be in a different thread, maybe even in an interrupt handler).

Comment: Which still begs the question, how do I orchestrate all of this. Some samples need to be played often (i.e.metronome). Other tracks however will need to stream data to the primary buffer. As I initially asked, I need some guidance in architecture on this one :-)

Comment: Juce is under a dual GPL and commercial license.  Last time I got pricing for commercial (e.g. closed source) use it was pretty reasonable and easily justified for the support that comes with it. It also has considerably more useful functionality for the OP's intended purpose than the PA has.

Comment: True. I wouldn't consider GPL as free though. I just wanted to provide another option, should Juce be too expensive for the OP, which I thought it might considering that he still uses XP.

Comment: Thanks Joe, your latest comments answer my original question.

Comment: Extended it some more with an example. Feel free to accept the answer if it is what you were originally looking for.

Comment: Joe, your answer is the best so far but I need more info on the following... How to define a period (as in period of n samples). To me a period is probably a bar (measure). Counter, is this this the counter to access my primary buffers? Obviously, I appreciate I need to use double buffering as a minimum.

Comment: Added an example which uses a single beat as the period. It should be easy enough to extend to 4-beat bars with a different sound for the first click

Answer (score 2):

As you've discovered, you are entering a world of pain.  If you're really building audio software for Windows XP and expect low latency, you'll definitely want to avoid any audio API provided by the operating system, and do as almost all commercial software does and use ASIO.  Whilst things got better, ASIO isn't going anyway any time soon.

To ease you pain considerably, I would recommend having a look at [Juce](http://www.juce.com), which is a cross-platform framework for building both audio host software and plugins.  It's been used to build many commercial products.

They've got many of the really nasty architectural hazards covered, and it comes with examples of both host applications and plug-ins to play with.

Comment: Thanks Marko, yes, I expect a world of pain. Out of interest, Juce must at some point use OS functions. Does it use ASIO? I'm just trying to fathom the best way forward :-)

Comment: It would appear so - although to what extent on which platforms I don't know (it would be a bit pointless on MacOSX for instance where ASIO is a thin shim on top of CoreAudio).  However, the point is that Juce *abstracts* this nasty detail away from you, yet provides a low-latency signal path.